# jquery 2 input fields validation and POST 1 value on successful submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 input fields for gathering any 1 input of User Choice. After Submit if user enters data on both fields it would be false. If no data on both fields also False. I know datastring , url , Ajax, POST - but I failed in validating input fields.

As of my experiment this given code is Sending BOTH fields of data on POST or GET methods ( even if I enter two different values it sends only NAME field Data for both field parameters as same value

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari007/5nxbc52f/5/) for complete understanding of my question..

```
$(document).ready(function {
$("#search").click(function({ 
    // checking whether Field is " EMPTY or NOT " by assigning valid class to it 

    $('#fname').on('input', function() {
        var input=$(this);
        var is_name=input.val();
        if(is_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
        else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
    });

    // checking whether Field is "EMPTY or NOT " assigning valid class to it

    $('#fnumber').on('input', function() {
        var input=$(this);
        var is_number=input.val();
        if(is_number){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
        else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
    });

    //checking whether user touched two fields ..

     if( $is_number.hasClass("valid") && $is_name.hasClass("valid") ) { 
               $("result").hide();
               $("error").show();
               $("wrong").hide();
        }
    //checking whether user Not touched two fields ..

    else if ( $is_number.hasClass("invalid") && $is_name.hasClass("invalid") ) {
            $("result").hide();
            $("error").hide();
            $("wrong").show();
        }
    // if user Touched only one field .... checking which one he/she is touched ...

    else {
        if(is_number.hasClass("valid") ) {
               $("result").show();
               $("error").hide();
               $("wrong").hide();
            $('#is_number').html('is_number');
        }
        else {
               $("result").show();
               $("error").hide();
               $("wrong").hide();
             $('#is_name').html('is_name');
        }
     }
 });
 $("result").hide();
 $("error").hide();
 $("wrong").show();
```

});

HTML Code

```
<form name="form" id="contact" method="post">
  <p> Number: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="form_number" size="15" name="fnumber"></input> </p>
   <p> Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="form_name" size="25" name="fname"></input> </p>              
   <input type="submit" name="search"/>
 </form> <br> <br>
<p id="result"> User Entered Value :-<span id="nam_value"> </span> <span id="num_value"> </span> </p>
<p id="error"> Use only One field to enter data </p>
<p id="wrong"> Enter any Information </p>
```

Comment: I just saw your code on Fiddle link provided by you. First of all, there are few error which i like to point you out. 1) Search button type is submit and there is no Id assign to it. Add id to it. Change type from "submit" to "button". On click of button to validate, check for values of input directly. Currently you have written "on" event when click on search button which is not valid and required. Hope this will help for start

Comment: The "input" event doesn't exists, you should use 'keydown' instead

Comment: You wouldn't use key down. The triggering even is the #search click, thus creating a keydown event would cause this to perform after the form is already submitted.

Comment: Actually I did that code by modifying.. Jquery main page example .... I tried for many cases which it was failing at first IF-CONDITION itself.... So I asked your suggestion ..some times small things makes more difficult

Comment: I think I have to check for twise ... Because.. Initially input is null... If user erases data then field is not null.. It was 0.. .as of my observe.. So I this nk I have to check every thing twise ... To make it perfect valid

Answer (score 1):

Ok there's a ton of things wrong here, I've been at it for about 30 minutes and I haven't found everything.

Here's where I've made it to: http://jsfiddle.net/4j4y2rq3/4/

First you were missing brackets.

```
$(document).ready(function {
  $("#search").click(function({
```

I added them in my fiddle.

I then fixed the element ids called in the validation to match the input fields. I cut some of the useless code, and replaced some of the calls in your if statements to correspond to an element, rather than the text value of the input. (i.e you cannot do this $('input').val().hasClass("valid"))

Some fixes that still need to occur:

Near the bottom you have a bunch of code like `$("result").show();` That is calling a tag like `<result>` you need to make an element with an id or class called result, then make it look like this `$('.result')` or `$('#result')`

You'll also need to trigger the validation before you post. If you trigger the validation of the form submission on the submit/#search, the post will override all of your javascript.